# Data decorating and Symfony2

Tags: symfony

Abstract question. Is there "data decorator" bundle for Symfony2? Or how would you solve elegantly data localization/formatting problems?

For example:

- float - decimals formatting, monetary data needs monetary formatting
- integers - formatting - 1'000'000 vs 1.000.000
- dates, times
- etc

I know that Symfony1 had some kind decorating going on in templates which would suit this exactly. It wasn't perfect, though and arised other problems.

Anybody knows, is there something? Or what would be the "correct" way for solving this problem?

Comment: What is "data decorator"? Is it a common term? Is it a concept from another framework?

Comment: There is [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). I googled a bit and found a [Rails gem](https://github.com/drapergem/draper) which is exactly what I'm asking for (only it is in Rails).

Answer (score 2):

Your question as it stands is too vague and answers can be considered primarily opinion-based, but you're aware that the native PHP functions do everything that you're asking for, right?

- Float, integer formatting: [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)
- Date/Time formatting: [`DateTime` class and its subsequent `format` functions](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Twig even uses the equivalent functions to achieve exactly what you're asking for: [`number_format`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/number_format.html) and the [`date`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html) filters.

This would be the correct standard - and although I have literally no experience with Symfony1, I haven't had any issue deploying a dozen Symfony2 projects using just these two functions to achieve the data decorating that you desire.

Comment: Of course I know all of them. And it is intended to be opinion-based ("Or how would you solve elegantly...?"). But I'd ask: which is more readable (in Twig for example): `{{ person.birthDate }}` (where person is "decorated"), or `{{ person.birthDate|date('date_format'|trans)) }}`